# What are these objects shown in the movie, Avatharam (2014)...?

Tags: movie, space, object-identification

In the movie, *[Avatharam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avatharam_(2014_Malayalam_film))* (2014), some entities are shown. Here are a few screenshots of them:

> [image: Image of unidentified objects from the film, "Avatharam" (2014).]
>
> [image: Image of unidentified objects from the film, "Avatharam" (2014).]
>
> [image: Image of unidentified objects from the film, "Avatharam" (2014).]

And here is a video itself:

Are these a part of science fiction? What are they?